# Rendering thousands of points

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, memory, rasterize

I am trying to render an image with some 120,000 `Point`s. Technically it's just 10,000 points, plus their reflection, plus 5 rotations of both of those sets, but I'm not sure that's relevant. The code I'm using is something like this:

```
Graphics[
 {
   PointSize[1/n],
   White, 
   g = Point /@ Join @@ {points, points.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}, 
   Array[Rotate[g, Pi #/3, {0, 0}] &, 6]
 },
 Background -> Black,
 ImageSize -> n*p,
 ImageMargins -> n (1 - p)/2
]
```

where `points` contains 10,000 (integer) coordinate pairs.

A reasonably representative set of inputs would be

```
points = RandomInteger[{0, 10000}, {10000, 2}];
n = 600;
p = 0.8;
```

In reality, the points are created from a Brownian tree [for this challenge over on PPCG.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42795/8478).

The problem is, I run out of memory. I don't actually need the resulting vector graphic, but wrapping the above in `Rasterize` doesn't help either (so I guess Mathematica does build the full vector graphic representation first anyway).

Is there a better way to rasterise a large number of points into an image? (Other than rounding all coordinates onto an `n`-by-`n` grid and using that as input to `Image`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yves showed you how to shave off a factor of 10, and in the following I'll shave off another factor of 10.

First, the original code (plus some data of mine to make it work):

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {1000, 2}];

n = 500;
p = .99;

g1 = Graphics[{PointSize[1/n], White, 
   g = Point /@ Join @@ {points, points.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}, 
   Array[Rotate[g, Pi #/3, {0, 0}] &, 6]}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> n*p, ImageMargins -> n (1 - p)/2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This takes more than 2 MB:

```
g1 // ByteCount
```

> 2468840

Using the trick Yves mentioned (`Point@` instead of `Point/@`):

```
g2 = Graphics[{PointSize[1/n], White, 
    g = Point[Join @@ {points, points.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}], 
    Array[Rotate[g, Pi #/3, {0, 0}] &, 6]}, Background -> Black, 
   ImageSize -> n*p, ImageMargins -> n (1 - p)/2];
```

It saves a lot indeed:

```
g2 // ByteCount
```

> 232648

Now, since most of the pixels are rotated or reflected pixels ones, we can use the space saving function `GeometricTransformation`. If you use it with various transformations on a given Graphics object it doesn't store all the various transformed sets, but just the original set plus the transformations themselves, resulting in huge savings:

```
g3 = Graphics[{PointSize[1/n], White,
   GeometricTransformation[
    GeometricTransformation[
     Point@points,
     {
      TranslationTransform[{0, 0}],
      ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]
      }
     ],
    {TranslationTransform[{0, 0}]}~Join~
     Array[RotationTransform[Pi #/3] &, 6]
    ]
   }, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> n*p, 
  ImageMargins -> n (1 - p)/2]
```

Indeed, this saves more than a factor of 10:

```
g3 // ByteCount
```

> 22448

Note that I used `GeometricTransformation` twice, once to get the original set plus its mirror image and once to rotate those two six times.

Obviously, given the different byte counts of g1, g2 and g3, their underlying graphics code must be different, but do we still get the same rasterized image?

```
Rasterize[g1] == Rasterize[g3]
```

> True

Comment: Very nice indeed! The actual mechanism used by `GeometricTransform`(esp. the memory-saving part) is not really well described in the docs, is it?

Comment: @YvesKlett True. For the close reader it is implied in the Details section: *GeometricTransformation[g,…] remains unchanged under evaluation, but affects how g is rendered.*

Comment: Hehe, you got me there.

Comment: @YvesKlett I suspect that `GeometricTransformation` is off-loaded onto the GPU.  Seems silly not to, based on my limited understanding of why there is a GPU in the first place. :)  -- Addendum in response to your latest reply: Yes, they don't say much about implementation details.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinBüttner My pleasure! I can imagine that reducing memory usage with a factor of 109 really helps ;-)

Answer (score 11):

One way to save memory is to use the multi-primitive syntax for `Point` (which should also render quite a bit faster)`:

```
coords = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}];
Point /@ coords // ByteCount
Point@coords // ByteCount
%/%% // N

(*176200

  16552

  0.0939387*)
```

For your example you simply drop one character to save a whole lot (about 90%) of kernel real estate:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[1/n], White, 
   g = Point /@ Join @@ {points, points.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}, 
   Array[Rotate[g, Pi #/3, {0, 0}] &, 6]}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> n*p, ImageMargins -> n (1 - p)/2] // ByteCount

(*24642656*)

Graphics[{PointSize[1/n], White, 
   g = Point@Join @@ {points, points.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}, 
   Array[Rotate[g, Pi #/3, {0, 0}] &, 6]}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> n*p, ImageMargins -> n (1 - p)/2] // ByteCount

(*2244952*)
```

Also works a treat for `Line` or `Polygon`...

Comment: Ah nice, thank you, I'll give that a go.

Comment: It's been a while since I tested it, but the front end handles the multi-primitive forms more quickly, too.  (Or the savings may be in how it is passed to the GPU -- I don't know about such things.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 yep, sometimes very useful for huge expressions. I think I read a post (mathgroup?) a few years ago which explained that this was due to reduced kernel-frontend communication or some such. Again, no explicit mention in the docs on the performance thing.

Comment: I notice the FE improvement most clearly in rotating 3D graphics.  I can only speculate how these data structures correspond to GPU data structures and commands.